# How to mount company network share?

Tags: network, macos, smb

I got a MacBook Air as my working computer running **MacOS Sierra 10.12.5**. Within the intranet at the company office we got a network share. Whenever I want to use it, I have to add it via the Finder using the **CMD + K** command.

> smb://server/share

This is then mounted as:

> /Volumes/share/

There are two problems or questions about it.

**Reconnect:** When I'm out of the network and back again, MacOS can't access the share again and I have to reconnect using the CMD + K command. Is there a way to add it as auto-connect so that MacOS tries to re-establish the link if possible?

**Name of volume:** Because of the manual reconnect, MacOS starts to increase the number of the volume again and again. This is only reset if I restart MacOS but not through hibernate/sleep mode. Is there a way to change this?

> /Volumes/share-1/
>
> /Volumes/share-2/

Answer (score 1):

One solution should fix both issues. You can work around the -1 and -2 issue by unmounting the volumes before disconnecting from the network (sleeping the Mac) or cleaning up in /Volumes before reconnecting.

The automatic mount is solved by a tool like:

- Apple Enterprise Connect
- [NoMAD](https://nomad.menu/) open source
- JAMF Connect - a commercially supported version of NoMAD

https://nomad.menu is free to use and your company can pay for support if desired. Apple Enterprise Connect is a paid product and Apple engineers come to your business to set it up and provide enterprise support for the tool. You buy it from your Apple sales contact and they can invite your team to a web presentation to see how it works if you wish before buying the tool and services.